# WMS-Layers with Orthophotos with a resolution of 10cm are not shown in Qfield

Tags: qgis, wms, qfield

I have a project with different layers in QGIS 3.6. Some of the layers are WMS layers with orthophotos. The orthophotos have different resolutions from 25 to 10cm. This works all very well.

But using this project in Qfield (System Android 4.4 and Qfield Lucendro 0.11.90), the WMS layers with orthophotos and a resolution of 12 or 10 cm are not shown. The sign which shows that the layer is loaded works normally but after a few seconds the orthophoto cannot be seen. Other layers with a resolution of 20 or 25cm are working correctly. I tried different options in QGIS but without success.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by loading all WMS-Layers new from the server und new configered the projekt. Now all WMS-Layers with the orthophotas are shown in Qfield.

Answer (score 0):

same problem, reinstalled qfield on the smartphone, solved it.